# Meta Box by Rilwis, Load metabox on all page templates EXCEPT the homepage

Tags: plugins, metabox

Using Rilwis' Meta Box plugin for custom metaboxes, is there a way that I can load a metabox on all page templates *except* `template-home.php`?

```
'only_on' => array(
    'template' => array( 'template-home.php' ),
),
```

I tried adding `!` before it but it didn't work.

Comment: Would you mind explaining what your frame of reference is? What is this about? What are you attempting to do? Etc. It isn't currently clear.

Comment: It's for a meta box script and the `only-on` part determines where the meta box(es) will display, in this case only on pages that use the `template-home.php` template. What I want to do is show the box on all pages EXCEPT those that use `template-home.php`

Comment: Which metabox script? My point is to offer as much information in the question (you can edit the question) so that you will get the best answer.

Comment: Meta Box by Rilwis although the `only_on` was a custom addition by another developer I think

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could flip the `rw_maybe_include()` function around and create a `rw_maybe_exclude()`

```
/**
 * Check if meta boxes is included
 *
 * @return bool
 */
function rw_maybe_exlude( $conditions ) {
    // Include in back-end only
    if ( ! defined( 'WP_ADMIN' ) || ! WP_ADMIN ) {
        return true;
    }

    // Always include for ajax
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) && DOING_AJAX ) {
        return false;
    }

    if ( isset( $_GET['post'] ) ) {
        $post_id = $_GET['post'];
    }
    elseif ( isset( $_POST['post_ID'] ) ) {
        $post_id = $_POST['post_ID'];
    }
    else {
        $post_id = false;
    }

    $post_id = (int) $post_id;
    $post    = get_post( $post_id );

    foreach ( $conditions as $cond => $v ) {
        // Catch non-arrays too
        if ( ! is_array( $v ) ) {
            $v = array( $v );
        }

        switch ( $cond ) {
            case 'id':
                if ( in_array( $post_id, $v ) ) {
                    return true;
                }
            break;
            case 'parent':
                $post_parent = $post->post_parent;
                if ( in_array( $post_parent, $v ) ) {
                    return true;
                }
            break;
            case 'slug':
                $post_slug = $post->post_name;
                if ( in_array( $post_slug, $v ) ) {
                    return true;
                }
            break;
            case 'template':
                $template = get_post_meta( $post_id, '_wp_page_template', true );
                if ( in_array( $template, $v ) ) {
                    return true;
                }
            break;
        }
    }

    // If no condition matched
    return false;
}
```

Then define your metabox with an `exclude_on` key

```
$prefix = 'rw_';

global $meta_boxes;

$meta_boxes = array();

$meta_boxes[] = array(
    'title'  => __( 'Meta Box Title', 'rwmb' ),
    'pages'    => array( 'post', 'page' ),
    'fields' => array(
        array(
            'name' => __( 'Your images', 'rwmb' ),
            'id'   => "{$prefix}img",
            'type' => 'plupload_image',
        ),
    ),
    'exclude_on'    => array(
        'template' => array( 'template-home.php' )
    ),
```

And finally register your metaboxes with a check against your new function.

```
/**
 * Register meta boxes
 *
 * @return void
 */
function rw_register_meta_boxes()
{
    global $meta_boxes;

    // Make sure there's no errors when the plugin is deactivated or during upgrade
    if ( class_exists( 'RW_Meta_Box' ) ) {
        foreach ( $meta_boxes as $meta_box ) {
            if ( isset( $meta_box['exclude_on'] ) && rw_maybe_exlude( $meta_box['exclude_on'] ) ) {
                continue;
            }

            new RW_Meta_Box( $meta_box );
        }
    }
}

add_action( 'admin_init', 'rw_register_meta_boxes' );
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a homepage check you can use which would probably be easier than checking the template using `is_front_page`, this works for static page's set to display on the home page.

If not you can try and use the `get_page_template` function and then match the strings.

```
$pagetemplate  = get_page_template();
if ( $pagetemplate == 'template-home.php' )
    //do something
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_front_page
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_template